# Retrofit. Как правильно построить класс для парсинга JSON

Tags: java, android, retrofit

С помощью Retrofit необходимо получить ответ от сервера. Ответ приходит в виде:

```
{
    "id": "LBI7cgq3pbM",
    "user": {
      "profile_image": {
        "small": "...",
        "medium": "...",
        "large": "..."
      }
      //еще поля
    }
    //еще поля
}
```

Класс у меня получается такой:

```
public class Photo {

    private String id;

    private User user;

}

public class User {

    private String username;

    @SerializedName("profile_image")
    private ProfileImage profileImage;

    public class ProfileImage  {
        @SerializedName("medium")
        private String url;
    }

}
```

Выглядит ужасно но работает. Для того чтобы получить ссылку на аватар пользователя пришлось создать вложенный класс. Но мне кажется должен быть способ достать до `user->profile_image->medium` без создания дополнительных классов, а просто грамотно прописать `@SerializedName`. **Вопрос**: действительно ли можно и как?

Comment: Есть вот такой сайт, который поможет Вам создать модельки по json http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Нет в Gson (да и других известных мне парсерах) такой аннотации, чтобы достать поле из вложенного объекта. Для этого нужно писать какстомный [десериализатор](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html), что по сути достать их ручками по ключам и проставить в нужные поля

Comment: @woesss, Понял, в общем это нормальная практика создавать по классу для каждого вложения.

Answer (score 1):

Для автоматического создания моделей рекомендую следующий сервис:

jsonschema2pojo.org

Автоматическое создание моделей сокращает время разработки.